# Issue on Renaming Image File On Upload Using

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

am trying to **Rename** an image when uploading it. I have a text field with id of  `newName`  now I would like to pass it into `FormData ( )`  and over write it on the file name in the PHP file
Here is the the code I have

```
<input type="text" id="newName" />
$(document).ready(function (e) {
var newName = $("#newName").val();
    $('#imageUploadForm').on('submit',(function(e) {      
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data:formData,
            cache:false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success:function(data){
                console.log("success");
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log("error");
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }));

    $("#ImageBrowse").on("change", function() {
        $("#imageUploadForm").submit();
    });
});
```

Can you please let me know how to do it?

Comment: Shouldn't be your `input` be of type `file` instead of `text`?

Comment: No, this is the text input which I would like to over write the name . it is not the input file one!

Comment: Why do you want to rename the file in `javascript` rather than using `PHP`?

Comment: Instead of "tell me how to do it" please tell us what happens when you run your code, why it isn't what you want to happen, and what you want to happen instead.

Comment: I want to enable user to change the image name as they desire!

Comment: @Air thanks for comment! but I think I am clear enough here! I would like to post a new name plus the ajax data into the server and use that name instead of file's base name

Comment: Again, why not `PHP`? Much simpler I guess...

Comment: @D4V1D, this is an Ajax call so I need to do this through jquery

Comment: Still, you'd have to treat the upload through `PHP`. Why not renaming the file while doing `move_uploaded_file()` for instance?

Comment: Please edit your post and add the `PHP` code you have for saving the image. also if you don not mind can you please share with us, what is your purpose to rename the file with the new name? if you want to save the file on the server, you may have duplicate filenames with this method. just saying!